# Tree : Performance comparison between stack implementation and recursive call of Traversal in BST

Tags: algorithm, performance, data-structures, time-complexity, binary-search-tree

well I am currently learning data structure and algorithm. I got two methods of traversal in binary search tree. 
**(1)-stack implementation**
 **(2)-recursive call method**

**which one performance wise is better?**

Comment: Depends on the actual implementation and the computer architecture.

Comment: Bot are the same in terms of time complexity

Comment: and what about running time complexity ??

Comment: Write them both and find out for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the algorithm remain same, performance should also be same. In your case: performance remains same because in both cases, stacks are used.

In, **stack implementation** programmer explicitly maintaining a stack for traversal. And in **recursive call method**, programs internal call stack is used for traversal.

**EDIT:**

> and what about running time complexity ??

Running time complexity would be same for both of the cases. But execution time could be different depending on the implementation. As there is no code/implementation provided, "in general sense, recursion could take much longer time because

> recursion (implemented naively) involves pushing a stack frame,
> jumping, returning, and popping back from the stack.

For more information you can check the following links:

1. [Is recursion faster than loops](https://www.quora.com/Is-recursion-faster-than-loops)
2. [Looping versus recursion for improved application performance](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/1307_col_paskin/1307_col_paskin.html)

Comment: In recursion at every recursive call a stack is maintained, but here I am maintaining only one stack explicitly

Comment: nope, there should not be any stack inside recursion method. 
Here you'll utilize recursions feature to ignore external stack maintenance.

Comment: but in recursive call stack is maintained implicitly in the method area.